# Index each json file then combine into one json with jq

Tags: json, merge, jq

I have a directory of json files, for example:

mock1.json

```json
[
    { "name": "John" },
    { "name": "Mary" }
]
```

mock2.json

```json
[
    { "name": "Nick" },
    { "name": "Luke" }
]
```

I learned that

```sh
jq -r 'to_entries'
```

will transform the format to:

```json
[
    {
        "key": 0,
        "value": { "name": "John" }
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": { "name": "Mary" }
    }
]
```

I also learned that:

```sh
jq -s add [PATH/*.json]
```

Combines all json files in specified path to one json object.

However, I'm struggling to index the json files then combine them. Something like:

```json
[
    {
        "key": 0,
        "value": { "name": "John" }
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": { "name": "Mary" }
    },
    {
        "key": 0,
        "value": { "name": "Nick" }
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": { "name": "Luke" }
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do it:

```sh
cat mock[12].json | jq -s 'map(to_entries) | flatten'
```

Or:

```sh
jq to_entries mock[12].json | jq -s flatten
```